# Visual C# HTML5 Video

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am building an windows app that will play videos that come from a website (not YouTube). This site has HTML5 video player. How can i access this video in my app? Is there a way to filter the website to just play the video in the web browser or what way should I follow for this. (It will look like Netflix but just play the videos of a particular website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the source url and put it into the video tag or you could use [videojs](http://videojs.com/getting-started/) - just replace the url to the MY_VIDEO.webm and MY_VIDEO.webm with the one from your source:

```
 <head>

   <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.8.8/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 -->
   <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
   <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
   poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg" data-setup="{}">
     <source src="MY_VIDEO.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
     <source src="MY_VIDEO.webm" type='video/webm'>
     <p class="vjs-no-js">
       To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
       <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
     </p>
   </video>

   <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.8.8/video.js"></script>
 </body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wz5oz6ye/